# How to take a screenshot of a section of the screen on Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, customization, screenshot

How can I take a screenshot of a selected region of my screen?
I already tried `PrtScr` but it captures only fullscreen screenshots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new shortcut, and set it to execute the command below:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -r
```

See [man xfce4-screenshooter](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xfce4-screenshooter.1.html) for more detail.

Other xfce-friendly screenshot apps [are listed here](https://alternativeto.net/software/xfce4-screenshooter/?platform=linux).

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> launches screenshooter with selector cursor

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to only capture the window in focus.